# Aligning structures to std140, CPU side

Tags: c++, opengl, uniform

I suppose this is a kind-of cross between a pure C++ question and an OpenGL question.  I have a uniform buffer and am allocating space in it of sizeof(ShaderData) bytes.  I'm using std140 layout on the GPU side in the shader.

According to std140 rules, I need to add padding in various places in my structure to make sure things like vectors are aligned correctly.  The structure below is an example (for my light):

```
struct ShaderData {

    float Light_Intensity;  
    float _pad1[3];    // align following vec3 on 4N boundary
    Math::Vec3f Light_Position;
    float _pad2;       // align following vec4 on 4N boundary
    Math::Colour4f Light_Ambient;
    Math::Colour4f Light_Diffuse;
    Math::Colour4f Light_Specular;    
    float Light_AttenuationMin;
    float Light_AttenuationMax;

} MyShaderData;
```

Is this the way people generally do things in C++, or are there special keywords or pragmas for aligning individual elements of a structure CPU side that are a little tidier?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No, in this way you just waste space. You have to find the optimized layout according to std140 rules.

- a `float` needs 4 bytes and it's 4 bytes aligned
- a `vec3` needs 12 bytes and it's 16 bytes aligned
- a `vec4` needs 16 bytes and it's 16 bytes aligned

This means that you can find a better layout for your struct:

```
float Light_Intensity;          X
float _pad1[3];                  XXX
Math::Vec3f Light_Position;         XXX
float _pad2;                           X
```

As you can see you are wasting 4 bytes and what's worse is the fact that you can just do something like:

```
Math::Vec3f Light_Position      XXX
float Light_Intensity;             X
```

To have it aligned and without the need to waste a byte. This works because `vec3` will be aligned to 16 bytes boundaries while the `float` will be still aligned to 4 bytes boundaries.

Comment: OK, correct, I saw that a moment ago.  But in the general case (rather than my specific case), what's the best way of putting padding in?  Is there *always* an optimised order that doesn't require it?  Seems unlikely.

Comment: AFAIK there is not a standardized way to define padding in a common way which is not like you are doing (fictitious struct members). There are some `#pragma` directives related to alignment but I'm unsure about how much are they standard. http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Structure_002dPacking-Pragmas.html

Comment: I guess you should go somethink like `#pragma pack(push,16)` to set the alignment and then `#pragma pack(pop)` to restore it after.

Comment: OK, that would look pretty horrendous.  Probably better just to slip in some float _pad and add a comment about intention.

Comment: You could use your own macro, eg `PADDING(4)` `PADDING(16)` if you feel more comfortable, surely better than `#pragma pack(push,16)`

Comment: @Robinson Apart from compiler-specific stuff (like `__declspec(align(16))` on MSVC, `__attribute__((aligned(16)))` for gcc), C++11 has the protable `alignas(16)` (though not supported by all compilers), just add those in front of the respective member declarations: `alignas(16) Math::Vec3f Light_Position`. Changing the struct packing to 16 would be a bit too strict for `float`s which don't need 16-aignment.

Comment: As iti s not mentioned here, note that for vec2 the rules are: "a vec2 needs 8 bytes and it's 8 bytes aligned"