# GLSL row_major mat4x3 mat3x4 reading/writing from UBO/SSBO

Tags: opengl, glsl

If I have all my shaders set to row_major with:

```
layout(row_major) uniform;
layout(row_major) buffer;
```

Using std140 and/or std430 layout what should happen when I read or write a mat4x3 from buffer objects?

Comment: It's not clear what you mean by "what should happen"? What should happen where? In GLSL? In your C code that feeds the buffer? Also, [please see this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38172696/734069).

Comment: I mean in terms of whether the reads and writes in those cases should be transposed - I have actually encountered a problem where nvidia and AMD are behaving differently with this and I am not clear on what the spec intends should actually happen.  Your link was quite helpful thank you - in that it does appear that for mat4x3/mat3x4 it's just safer to write manual code to write and read such values given driver issues