# OpenGL Uniform Standard Buffer Alignment confusion

Tags: c++, opengl, shader

I have been reading about std140 Uniform block in OpenGL Superbible 6th edition, where in page 111 the following example is given :

```
layout(std140) uniform TransformBlock
{
      //Member                        base alignment    offset  aligned offset
      float scale ;                   // 4              0       0
      vec3 translation;               // 16             4       16
      float rotation[3];              // 16             28      32 (rotation[0])
                                      //                        48 (rotation[1])
                                      //                        64 (rotation[2])
      mat4 projection_matrix;         // 16             80      80 (column 0)
                                      //                        96 (column 1)       
                                      //                        112 (column 2)   
                                      //                        128 (column 3)                                    
}
```

I am having hard time understanding the alignments, even using the rules that have described earlier in that page, it still don't make sense.To be specific thing that confuses me is :

1. What is the Offset and what is aligned offset, why 2 different offset?
2. Why is the rotation[0] offset starts at 28, and why aligned offset is 32?

Hopefully someone can clear my confusions.I would highly appreciate.
Thanks

Answer (score 2):

> What is the Offset

The byte offset that the variable *would have had* if not for its alignment requirements.

> and what is aligned offset,

The byte offset it actually has.

> why 2 different offset?

Because if the variable had different alignment requirements, then the actual offset would be different. For example, given the above code, `translation` has the aligned offset of 16 because of its alignment requirements. However, if `translation` were a `float`, then it would have an aligned offset of 4. If it were a `vec2`, it would have an aligned offset of 8.

> Why is the rotation[0] offset starts at 28,

Because a `vec3` (which is [something you should *never use*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38172697/734069)) is 3 floats.

> and why aligned offset is 32?

Because under std140 rules, the base alignment of *any array*, regardless of the type of its elements, is always rounded up to the alignment of a `vec4`. AKA: 16 bytes.

Comment: "Because a vec3 (which is something you should never use) is 3 floats"  , ok but why is rotation starts at 28, because if i start from beginning, scale starts at 0,translation at 4, then isn't that should start at (4 + 12)16

Comment: @aaa111: As I said, the aligned offset is the offset the variable *actually has*. The non-aligned offset is purely *speculative*. So translation starts at 16.