# Alignments of members in Unifrom buffer objects

Tags: opengl

I am having Uniform buffer object:

```
layout (std140) uniform ubo{
    vec3 A;
    float B;
    vec4 C;
    vec4 D;
    vec4 E;
    vec4 F;
    float G;
};
```

I am assuming offset of each of them as A: 0, B: 12, C: 16, D: 32 E: 48 F:64 G:80

But it doesn't seem so if i use all of them as vec4s everything works fine.
What would be the offsets of each of them?

I tried with these new offsets:
A: 0, B: 16, C: 32, D: 48 E: 64 F:80 G:96 but it still doesn't work

Comment: Please [see this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38172696/should-i-ever-use-a-vec3-inside-of-a-uniform-buffer-or-shader-storage-buffer-o/38172697#38172697)

Comment: I am not using structures for passing the data to GPU. I am using void pointer with offsets

Comment: "Implementation support is fuzzy"

Answer (score -1):

From ARB_uniform_buffer_object

> ```
>   (1) If the member is a scalar consuming <N> basic machine units, the
>       base alignment is <N>.
>
>   (2) If the member is a two- or four-component vector with components
>       consuming <N> basic machine units, the base alignment is 2<N> or
>       4<N>, respectively.
>
>   (3) If the member is a three-component vector with components consuming
>       <N> basic machine units, the base alignment is 4<N>.
>
>   (4) If the member is an array of scalars or vectors, the base alignment
>       and array stride are set to match the base alignment of a single
>       array element, according to rules (1), (2), and (3), and rounded up
>       to the base alignment of a vec4. The array may have padding at the
>       end; the base offset of the member following the array is rounded up
>       to the next multiple of the base alignment.
>
>   (5) If the member is a column-major matrix with <C> columns and <R>
>       rows, the matrix is stored identically to an array of <C> column
>       vectors with <R> components each, according to rule (4).
>
>   (6) If the member is an array of <S> column-major matrices with <C>
>       columns and <R> rows, the matrix is stored identically to a row of
>       <S>*<C> column vectors with <R> components each, according to rule
>       (4).
>
>   (7) If the member is a row-major matrix with <C> columns and <R> rows,
>       the matrix is stored identically to an array of <R> row vectors
>       with <C> components each, according to rule (4).
>
>   (8) If the member is an array of <S> row-major matrices with <C> columns
>       and <R> rows, the matrix is stored identically to a row of <S>*<R>
>       row vectors with <C> components each, according to rule (4).
>
>   (9) If the member is a structure, the base alignment of the structure is
>       <N>, where <N> is the largest base alignment value of any of its
>       members, and rounded up to the base alignment of a vec4. The
>       individual members of this sub-structure are then assigned offsets 
>       by applying this set of rules recursively, where the base offset of
>       the first member of the sub-structure is equal to the aligned offset
>       of the structure. The structure may have padding at the end; the 
>       base offset of the member following the sub-structure is rounded up
>       to the next multiple of the base alignment of the structure.
>
>   (10) If the member is an array of <S> structures, the <S> elements of
>        the array are laid out in order, according to rule (9).
> ```

Each vec3 counts as vec4 according to spec. I think that is only surprise that caused trouble for you.

Comment: Oops. I made error there vec3 has alignment of 16 but still size of 12 and following float has alignment of 4 making vec3+float fit to 16 bytes. That means your original offset calculation was perfectly valid. That leaves a question why doesn't it work then. You could test changing vec3 to vec4 and see if you get it working then with all objects aligned to 16.

Comment: I already have it working with all vec4s but question is what's wrong with current one?

Comment: vec4 and access w as separate scalar is easier and more portable to implement. vec4 AB; vec4 C; ...  Then do vec3 A = vec3(AB.xyz); float B = AB.w; That is same idea that Nicol's managed to post while I was still thinking why offsets are going wrong for you.