# Array of structures into Compute Shader

Tags: opengl, shader, opengl-4, compute-shader, shader-storage-buffer

Writing a simple compute shader in OpenGL to understand how it works, I can't manage to obtain the wanted result.

I want to pass to my compute shader an array of structures colourStruct to color an output texture.

I would like to have a red image when "wantedColor" = 0 in my compute shader and a green image "wantedColor" = 1, blue for 2.

But I actually have only red when "wantedColor" = 1 or 2 or 3 and black when "wantedColor" > 2...

If someone has an idea, or maybe I did not understand the compute shader inputs ideas.

Thank you for your help, here is the interesting part of my code.

My compute shader :

```
 #version 430 compatibility

layout(std430, binding=4) buffer Couleureuh
{
  vec3 Coul[3]; // array of structures
};

layout(local_size_x = 1, local_size_y = 1) in;
layout(rgba32f, binding = 0) uniform image2D img_output;

void main() {

  // base pixel colour for image
  vec4 pixel = vec4(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);

  // get index in global work group i.e x,y, position
  ivec2 pixel_coords = ivec2(gl_GlobalInvocationID.xy);
  ivec2 dims = imageSize (img_output);


  int colorWanted = 0;
  pixel = vec4(Coul[colorWanted], 1.0);

  // output to a secific pixel in the image
  imageStore (img_output, pixel_coords, pixel);

}
```

Compute shader and SSBO initialization:

```
    GLuint structBuffer;
    glGenBuffers(1, &structBuffer);
    glBindBuffer(GL_SHADER_STORAGE_BUFFER, structBuffer);
    glBufferData(GL_SHADER_STORAGE_BUFFER, 3*sizeof(colorStruct), NULL, GL_STATIC_DRAW);

        GLint bufMask = GL_MAP_WRITE_BIT | GL_MAP_INVALIDATE_BUFFER_BIT; // invalidate makes a ig difference when re-writting

    colorStruct *coul;
    coul = (colorStruct *) glMapBufferRange(GL_SHADER_STORAGE_BUFFER, 0, 3*sizeof(colorStruct), bufMask);


    coul[0].r = 1.0f;
    coul[0].g = 0.0f;
    coul[0].b = 0.0f;

    coul[1].r = 0.0f;
    coul[1].g = 1.0f;
    coul[1].b = 0.0f;

    coul[2].r = 0.0f;
    coul[2].g = 0.0f;
    coul[2].b = 1.0f;

    glUnmapBuffer(GL_SHADER_STORAGE_BUFFER);

    glBindBufferBase(GL_SHADER_STORAGE_BUFFER, 4, structBuffer);

    m_out_texture.bindImage();

    // Launch compute shader
    m_shader.use();

    glDispatchCompute(m_tex_w, m_tex_h, 1);

    // Prevent samplign before all writes to image are done
    glMemoryBarrier(GL_SHADER_IMAGE_ACCESS_BARRIER_BIT);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`vec3` are always 16-byte aligned. As such, when they're in an array, they act like `vec4`s. Even with `std430` layout.

[Never use `vec3` in interface blocks](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38172697/734069). You should either use an array of `float`s (individually access the 3 members you want) or an array of `vec4` (with an unused element).