# how can i load an array of uniform buffer objects into the shader?

Tags: c++, glsl, vulkan

shader code:

```
// UBO for MVP matrices   
layout (binding = 0) uniform UniformBufferObject {
        mat4 model;
        mat4 view;
        mat4 proj;
} ubo;
```

this works fine because its just one struct and I can set the `VkWriteDescriptorSet.descriptorCount` to 1. But how can I create an array of those structs?

```
// Want to do something like this
// for lighting calculations
layout (binding = 2) uniform Light {
    vec3 position;
    vec3 color;
} lights[4];
```

I have the data for all of the four lights stored in one buffer. When I set the `VkWriteDescriptorSet.descriptorCount` to four, 
Do I have to create four `VkDescriptorBufferInfo`? If so, I dont know what to put into offset and range.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All of the blocks in a uniform buffer array live in the same descriptor. However, they are still different blocks; they get a different `VkDescriptorBufferInfo` info object. So those blocks don't have to come from sequential regions of storage.

Note: The KHR_vulkan_glsl extension [gets this wrong](https://github.com/KhronosGroup/GLSL/blob/master/extensions/khr/GL_KHR_vulkan_glsl.txt), if you look pay close attention. It notes that arrays of opaque types should go into a single descriptor, but arrays of interface blocks don't. The actual glslangValidator compiler (and SPIR-V and Vulkan) do handle it as I described.

However, you cannot access the elements of an interface block array with anything other than dynamically uniform expressions. And even *that* requires having a certain feature available; without that feature, you can only access the array with *constant* expressions.

What you probably want is an array *within* the block, not an array *of* blocks:

```
struct Light
{
  vec4 position; //(NEVER use `vec3` in blocks)
  vec4 color;
};

layout (set = 0, binding = 2, std140) uniform Lights {
  Light lights[4];
};
```

This means that you have a single descriptor in binding slot 2 (`descriptorCount` is 1). And the buffer's data should be 4 sequential structs.

Comment: `NEVER use vec3 in blocks` because of std140 size assumptions or any other reason?

Comment: @MahanGM: For [these reasons](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38172696/734069)