# Should I use vec3 or vec4 as color type in glsl?

Tags: glsl

guys. I am learning glsl for WebGL application. I have problem about choosing color type in glsl.

It seems I can use both `vec3` and `vec4` as color. After researching, I found THREE.js use `vec3`:

```
// from https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/dev/src/renderers/shaders/ShaderChunk/lights_phong_pars_fragment.glsl
struct BlinnPhongMaterial {
    vec3    diffuseColor;
    vec3    specularColor;
    float   specularShininess;
    float   specularStrength;
};
```

But in Babylon.js, osgjs, playcanvas, all of them use `vec4`.

What's the difference between using `vec3` and `vec4` for color type ?

Which should I choose ?

Thanks.

Comment: In a `vec3` you can store the RGB color channels. In a `vec4` you can store the alpha channel too. But probably the answer to [Should I ever use a `vec3` inside of a uniform buffer or shader storage buffer object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38172696/should-i-ever-use-a-vec3-inside-of-a-uniform-buffer-or-shader-storage-buffer-o) is of interest in this case.