# Migrate to QT6, pass Qcolor to Shader through uniform buffer

Tags: glsl, shader, qt6

I am migrating our code from Qt5 to Qt6,
I want to pass a QColor to the color in our shader, and use the color to determine fragColor in the shader. The original design is like:

```
layout(std140, binding = 0) uniform buf {
    mat4 qt_Matrix;
    float qt_Opacity;
    vec4 color
    float size;
};
```

Then Qt code, I pass the data to the uniform buffer:

```
if (state.isMatrixDirty()) {
    const QMatrix4x4 m = state.combinedMatrix();
    memcpy(buf->data(), m.constData(), 64);
    changed = true;
}

if(state.isOpacityDirty()) {
    const float opacity = state.opacity();
    memcpy(buf->data() + 64, &opacity, 4);
    changed = true;
}

auto *customMaterial = static_cast<ArcMaterial *>(newMaterial);
if (oldMaterial != newMaterial || customMaterial->uniforms.dirty) {
    memcpy(buf->data() + 68, &customMaterial->uniforms.color, 28);
    memcpy(buf->data() + 96, &customMaterial->uniforms.size, 4);
    customMaterial->uniforms.dirty = false;
    changed = true;
}
```

But the strange thing is vec4 is 28byte and Qcolor is 16 byte, and I am not able to send the Qcolor directly to the shader.

So redesign is I send rgba separately to the shader:

```
layout(std140, binding = 0) uniform buf {
    mat4 qt_Matrix;  //offset 0
    float qt_Opacity; //offset 64
    float size;  //offset 68
    float red;  //offset 72
    float green;  //offset 76
    float blue;  //offset 80
    float alpha;  //offset 84
};
fragColor = vec4(red, green, blue, alpha) * qt_Opacity * tt;
```

Qt code:

```
if (state.isMatrixDirty()) {
    const QMatrix4x4 m = state.combinedMatrix();
    memcpy(buf->data(), m.constData(), 64);
    changed = true;
}

if(state.isOpacityDirty()) {
    const float opacity = state.opacity();
    memcpy(buf->data() + 64, &opacity, 4);
    changed = true;
}

auto *customMaterial = static_cast<ArcMaterial *>(newMaterial);
if (oldMaterial != newMaterial || customMaterial->uniforms.dirty) {
    memcpy(buf->data() + 68, &customMaterial->uniforms.size, 4);
    float red = customMaterial->uniforms.color.red() / 255.0;
    memcpy(buf->data() + 72, &red, 4);
    float green = customMaterial->uniforms.color.green() / 255.0;
    memcpy(buf->data() + 76, &green, 4);
    float blue = customMaterial->uniforms.color.blue() / 255.0;
    memcpy(buf->data() + 80, &blue, 4);
    float alpha = customMaterial->uniforms.color.alpha() / 255.0;
    memcpy(buf->data() + 84, &alpha, 4);
    customMaterial->uniforms.dirty = false;
    changed = true;
}
```

Having two questions:

1. why the size of vec4 is 28 bytes instead of 16 byte?
2. Is it possible to pass Qcolor directly to the color variable in shader?

Comment: Your code uses `memcpy` to copy a non-POD type (`QColor` in this case) making certain assumptions about that types implementation.  That's almost certainly undefined behaviour.  Also, how did you determine that the size of `vec4` is 28 bytes?

Comment: If I remove the vec4 color from the uniform buffer, I tried to print the buffer size on qt side, it is (64+4+4) = 72 bytes. Then if I add the vec4 color, the buffer size is 100 bytes.

Comment: Also according to this document: https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qml-qtquick-shadereffect.html#shader-inputs-and-resources
QColor is mapped to vec4 in the shader

Comment: Ok, I think I misunderstood your question.  The real issue here is the fact that you're making all sorts of invalid assumptions about the structure/buffer layout.  Please read about the [std140 layout](https://registry.khronos.org/OpenGL/specs/gl/glspec45.core.pdf#page=159) paying particular attention to alignment requirements.  You might also want to look at [this related post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55926772/i-need-explanation-about-std140-uniform-blocks-offsets).

Comment: Ok, thanks for your message! This helps a lot!

So if my understanding is right, in my uniform buffer is like:
offset 0(qt_Matrix) | offset 64 (qt_opacity) | offset 80 (base alignment should be 16 for vec4) (color) | offset 96 (size)