# When do GLSL interface block layouts agree with C/C++ structures?

Tags: glsl

I am reading about std140 and std430 layouts in GLSL.

Consider, in C++:

```
struct Foo
{
    glm::vec4 alpha;
    float     beta;
    float     gamma;
    glm::vec4 delta;
    float     epsilon;
};
```

In GLSL:

```
uniform (layout=std140) MyUniformBlock
{
    vec4  alpha;
    float beta;
    float gamma;
    vec4  delta;
    float epsilon;
};
```

If I'm reading the documentation correctly, the offsets in `MyUniformBlock` will be 0, 16, 32, 48, 64, bytes: all multiples of `sizeof(vec4)==16`. Right?

However, in C/C++, it is permitted for `gamma` to have an offset of 20 bytes, right?

So under what conditions will the C/C++ struct and the GLSL interface block have the same layout?

If I use `layout=packed` and give the struct `__attribute__ ((packed))` or equivalent, is that guaranteed to match?

Also, consider

```
Foo array [N];
```

If C/C++ permits `sizeof(Foo)` to be *not* a multiple of `sizeof(vec4)` because there is no padding after the last element, does that cause problems if I try to send the whole of `array` to the buffer with `glBufferData`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> If I'm reading the documentation correctly, the offsets in MyUniformBlock will be 0, 16, 32, 48, 64, bytes: all multiples of sizeof(vec4)==16. Right?

No. A naked `float` in `std140` has a base alignment of 4 bytes and takes up 4 bytes. Your structure's offsets are:

```
uniform (layout=std140) MyUniformBlock
{
    vec4  alpha;     //offset 0,     size 16,    min-alignment 16
    float beta;      //offset 16,    size 4,     min-alignment 4
    float gamma;     //offset 20,    size 4,     min-alignment 4
    vec4  delta;     //offset 32,    size 16,    min-alignment 16
    float epsilon;   //offset 48,    size 4,     min-alignment 4
};
```

> If I use `layout=packed` and give the struct `__attribute__ ((packed))` or equivalent, is that guaranteed to match?

`packed` layout gives you *fewer* guarantees than `std140`. In fact, it gives you basically nothing. You can't even assume that all the members you specify in the block will contribute to the layout, because compilers are allowed to optimize away the storage for any variable that you *don't use*. You can't assume anything with `packed`; you must always query the layout explicitly.

Broadly speaking, `std140` will match most compilers' natural C and C++ layout, so long as:

1. You [never use `vec3`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38172697/734069). Note that this applies to matrices that have 3 columns/rows (depending on your matrix orientation).
2. You [`alignas`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/alignas)/[`_Alignas`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/_Alignas) your vector members properly. `vec2` objects must be 8-byte aligned, and `vec4` must be 16-byte aligned. Note that this applies to matrix types that have 2 or 4 columns/rows too.

   C's `_Alignas` feature only applies to variable declarations, so you can't apply it to the type. You have to put it on each variable as you use it.
3. Under `std140`, you never make arrays of anything that isn't a `vec4` or equivalent.
4. Under `std140`, struct members of a block should be aligned to 16-bytes.

If you don't follow these rules, then your C or C++ structure layout will have to be different from the GLSL equivalent in order to match up properly. For example, a `float array[5]` in GLSL would have to be a `vec4 array[5]` in C or C++.