# OpenGl Sending 48 bytes in UniformBuffer but glsl expects 60

Tags: c++, opengl, glsl

I have a C++ struct:

```cpp
struct PointLight
{
    glm::vec3 Position = glm::vec3(0.0f);
    glm::vec3 Ambient = glm::vec3(0.25f);
    glm::vec3 Diffuse = glm::vec3(1.0f);
    glm::vec3 Specular = glm::vec3(1.0f);
};
```

And I want to send this struct to glsl struct That is set up as follows:

```cpp
struct PointLight
{
    vec3 position;
    vec3 ambient;
    vec3 diffuse;
    vec3 specular;
};
```

So I create a UniformBuffer:

```cpp
glGenBuffers(1, &ID);
glBindBuffer(GL_UNIFORM_BUFFER, ID);
glBufferData(GL_UNIFORM_BUFFER, sizeof(PointLight), NULL, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
glBindBuffer(GL_UNIFORM_BUFFER, 0);
glBindBufferBase(GL_UNIFORM_BUFFER, 1, ID);
```

Then I update it every frame:

```cpp
glBindBuffer(GL_UNIFORM_BUFFER, ID);
glBufferSubData(GL_UNIFORM_BUFFER, 0, sizeof(PointLight), &light[0]); //First and only element PointLight in my lights vector
```

And Then I receive it inside shader like so:

```cpp
layout (std140, binding = 1) uniform u_Lights
{
    PointLight[NR_POINT_LIGHTS] u_PointLights;
};
```

`NR_POINT_LIGHTS` is 1

The problem is that shader acts like the Specular is set to 0 so I checked RenderDoc and it turns out that shader Need 60 bytes and only 48 bytes are provided so I did something like this:

```cpp
struct PointLight
{
    glm::vec3 Position = glm::vec3(0.0f);
    glm::vec3 Ambient = glm::vec3(0.25f);
    glm::vec3 Diffuse = glm::vec3(1.0f);
    glm::vec3 Specular = glm::vec3(1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);
    glm::vec actualSpecular = glm::vec3(1.0f); 
};
```

And then the value stored in `actualSpecular` works inside the shader. How did that happend and why does glsl expect 60 bytes from me? And where did the `Specular` disappear?

**Solution:** here's a link to answer that covers this problem:
[Should I ever use a `vec3` inside of a uniform buffer or shader storage buffer object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38172696/should-i-ever-use-a-vec3-inside-of-a-uniform-buffer-or-shader-storage-buffer-o)

Comment: @Rabbid76: Please mark questions as duplicates when they are duplicates; don't just link to them.

Comment: @Rabbid76: Yes. I wrote that question specifically to be a dupe-target for all questions involving the GLSL sizes involving vec3s that don't match their C/C++ apparent equivalents. The answer tells you exactly why the code is broken and exactly what you need to do to fix it.

Comment: @NicolBolas should I delete this question then?

Comment: @Szahu: You don't need to delete a question just because it's been asked before. Such questions act as useful signposts for people to find via search engines.

Comment: @NicolBolas Okay then. Thanks for help, You got me covered as usual!