# Compute to Graphics Dependencies

Tags: opengl, graphics, vulkan

I am doing a Marching cube algorithm in a Compute shader. The vertices generated by the compute stage will be input to the vertex stage.

```
Compute -> Vertices -> Render
```

There is no way of knowing how many vertices that the compute stage will output, so I need a `storage buffer` looking something like this:

```
layout(set = 1, binding = 0) buffer Count{
  int value;
} count;

layout(set = 2, binding = 0) buffer Mesh {
  vec4 vertices[1<<15];
} mesh;
```

The vertices do not need a roundtrip to the CPU, but the count is a variable used by the `vkCmdDraw` command. So I need to put the count buffer in host visible memory, map that memory and do a memcpy after the compute stage. Is this a good way of solving this problem or is there some other way where I don't have to read back data to the CPU?

Comment: [Don't use `vec3` in interface blocks](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38172697/734069).

Comment: Good point, I changed it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, this is exactly what [vkCmdDrawIndirect](https://www.khronos.org/registry/vulkan/specs/1.2-extensions/html/vkspec.html#vkCmdDrawIndirect) is for. The vertex count is stored in a `Vkuffer`, which makes the CPU round-trip unnecessary.