# Why do I got junk data, when sending a structure to shader storage buffer?

Tags: c++, opengl, glsl, shader, memory-alignment

I am working on an opengl based raytracer application in c++. I would like to send data from the cpu side to the fragment shader. The data is a bounding volume hierarchies (BVH) tree.
Unfortunately on the shader side I got junk data, when I am trying to write out the coordinates as color with gl_fragcolor. I don't know why. Any help is appreciated.

I have this structure on CPU side:

```
struct FlatBvhNode {

        glm::vec4 min;   
        glm::vec4 max;
        int order;
        bool isLeaf;
        bool createdEmpty;
        vector<glm::vec4> indices;

        FlatBvhNode() { }

        FlatBvhNode(glm::vec3 min, glm::vec3 max, int ind, bool isLeaf, bool createdEmpty, vector<glm::vec3> indices) {
            this->min=glm::vec4(min.x, min.y, min.z, 1.0f);
            this->max=glm::vec4(max.x, max.y, max.z, 1.0f);
            this->order=ind;
            this->isLeaf=isLeaf;
            this->createdEmpty=createdEmpty;

            indices.reserve(2);
            for (int i = 0; i < indices.size(); i++) {
                this->indices.push_back(glm::vec4(indices.at(i).x, indices.at(i).y, indices.at(i).z, 1));
            }
        }
    };
```

I would like to receive the above structure in the fragment shader as:

```
struct FlatBvhNode{     //base aligment     aligned offset
    vec3 min;           // 16 byte          0
    vec3 max;           // 16 byte          16
    int order;          // 4 byte           20
    bool isLeaf;        // 4 byte           24
    bool createdEmpty;  // 4 byte           28
    vec3 indices[2];    // 32 byte          32
};
```

I am not sure that the aligned offsets are right. I have read that vec3s are treated as 16 bytes , booleans and integers as 4 bytes. Secondly the aligned offset has to be equal or multiple of the base aligment.

I am sending the above structure with these code:

```
    vector<BvhNode::FlatBvhNode>* nodeArrays=bvhNode.putNodeIntoArray();
    unsigned int nodesArraytoSendtoShader;
    glGenBuffers(1, &nodesArraytoSendtoShader);
    glBindBuffer(GL_SHADER_STORAGE_BUFFER, nodesArraytoSendtoShader);

    glBufferData(GL_SHADER_STORAGE_BUFFER, nodeArrays->size() * sizeof(BvhNode::FlatBvhNode),  nodeArrays, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
    glBindBufferRange(GL_SHADER_STORAGE_BUFFER, 2, nodesArraytoSendtoShader, 0, nodeArrays->size() * sizeof(BvhNode::FlatBvhNode));
    glBindBuffer(GL_SHADER_STORAGE_BUFFER, 0);
```

Comment: `vector<glm::vec4> indices;` is an object containing a pointer to dynamic memory. You've to use [`std::array`](https://de.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array). In c++ code the data types are `std::vec4`. In the shader the types are `vec3`. Please read  [Should I ever use a `vec3` inside of a uniform buffer or shader storage buffer object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38172696/should-i-ever-use-a-vec3-inside-of-a-uniform-buffer-or-shader-storage-buffer-o)

Comment: ... and read [OpenGL 4.6 API Core Profile Specification; 7.6.2.2 Standard Uniform Block Layout](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL/specs/gl/glspec46.core.pdf#page=168&zoom=100,0,381)

Comment: I believe you, that std::array is more relevant but, I was using std::vector in an other case and everything seemed fine, except one thing: on the cpu side I have to use vec4 and on the gpu side vec3s

Comment: No you are wrong. The content of `vector<glm::vec4> indices;` is not what you expect it to be. Use a debugger an investigate the memory. You can use `std::vector` for the buffer, but not for an element in a structure, when the structure is an element of the buffer. Please lern the basics.

Comment: Ok, I see. I will check the basics.

Comment: So Vec3 is treated as Vec4 in GLSL and as far as I understand the only difference between std140 and std430 is that the latter one doesn't put padding at the end of the structs or arrays. I suppose the purpose of padding is for making the cpu read the memory less times.
Anyway I am also sending some primitive coordinates from cpu side as vec4 and receive these in a SSBO of frag shader as a vec3 array. The object appears in the window, so It seems fine. But when I change vec3 array to vec4 in frag shader's ssbo, the object appears in a wrong way. What can be the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you specify the [Shader Storage Buffer Object](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Shader_Storage_Buffer_Object), then you have to use the `std430` qualifier.
See [OpenGL 4.6 API Core Profile Specification; 7.6.2.2 Standard Uniform Block Layout](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL/specs/gl/glspec46.core.pdf#page=168&zoom=100,0,381).

If you want to use the following data structure in the shader:

```c
struct FlatBvhNode
{     
                        // base aligment    aligned offset
    vec4 min;           // 16 byte          0
    vec4 max;           // 16 byte          16
    int  order;         // 4 byte           32
    int  isLeaf;        // 4 byte           36
    int  createdEmpty;  // 4 byte           40
    vec4 indices[2];    // 32 byte          48
};

layout(std430) buffer TNodes
{
    FlatBvhNode nodes[];
}
```

then you have to consider, that `indices` is an array of type `vec4`. Hence `indices` is aligned to 16 bytes.

This corresponds to the following data structure in c ++

```cpp
struct FlatBvhNode {

        glm::vec4 min;   
        glm::vec4 max;
        int order;
        int isLeaf;
        int createdEmpty;
        int dummy; // alignment
        std::array<glm::vec4, 2> indices;
}
```

Note, while [`std::vector`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) encapsulates dynamic size arrays, [`std::array`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array) encapsulates fixed size arrays. `std::array<glm::vec4, 2>` corresponds to `glm::vec4[2]`, but `std::vector<glm::vec4>` is more like `glm::vec4*` and some additional size information.

Comment: "When you specify the then you have to use" something missing from the sentence. Btw, thank you for your help!

Comment: I tried your solution. Everything is fine except the booleans. When I write FragColor = vec4(nodes[0].isLeaf, 1, 1, 1); to get cyan or white color, it is always giving me white no matter isLeaf is true or false. But the other variables are fine.

Comment: @Tom I recommend to use `int` instead of `bool` (on both sides).