# Not able to understand alignment rules of OpenGL SSBOs

Tags: opengl, glsl

I have the following array of structs in glsl SSBO:

```
struct node {

  vec3 min, max;

  int hitNext;   
  int missNext;    
  int firstTri, numTris;
};
layout(std430, binding = 3) readonly buffer Nodes {
  node[] nodes;
};
```

I am passing them a bytebuffer where I have stored the data in the following format:

```
4 bytes min.x, 4 bytes min.y, 4 bytes min.z, 4 bytes 1.0f,
4 bytes max.x, 4 bytes max.y, 4 bytes max.z, 4 bytes 1.0f,
4 bytes hitNext, 4 bytes missNext, 4 bytes firstTrue, 4 bytes numTris
```

But glsl is not reading the data properly. If I change the `vec3` in the struct definition to `vec4` it works perfectly. But why is that the case? According to the OpenGL specs won't this be the alignment?:

```
struct node {               //Base alignment    Aligned Offset
  vec3 min;                 //  16                  0

  vec3 max;                 //  16                  16

  int hitNext;              //  4                   32

  int missNext;             //  4                   36

  int firstTri, numTris;    //  4                   40
                            //  4                   44
};
layout(std430, binding = 3) readonly buffer Nodes {
  node[] nodes;             //  16                  48
};
```

But this alignment matches up with the data I'm passing in. Why does this not work but `vec4` works?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> ```
> struct node {               //Base alignment    Aligned Offset   
>   vec3 min;                 //  16                  0
>   vec3 max;                 //  16                  16
>   int hitNext;              //  4                   32
> ```

Nope, that's not what the spec says. A `vec3` may just need an *alignment* of 16 bytes, but it does not *consume* 16 bytes. Since the base alignment of the element following it is just 4, we end up with an aligned offset of `28` for `hitNext`.

This is just another instance of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38172696/2327517).