# Contents of UBO are all the same according to the fragment shader

Tags: c++, opengl, glsl, glm-math, raytracing

I have a UBO initialized like this:

```
glGenBuffers(1, &sphereUBO);
glBindBuffer(GL_UNIFORM_BUFFER, sphereUBO);
glBufferData(GL_UNIFORM_BUFFER, sizeof(SphereUBO) * sphereData.size(), nullptr, GL_DYNAMIC_DRAW);
glBindBufferBase(GL_UNIFORM_BUFFER, 0, sphereUBO);

glUniformBlockBinding(rtShader.ID, glGetUniformBlockIndex(shaderProgram, "Spheres"), 0);

rtShader.setInt("u_numSpheres", sphereData.size());
```

Above that, I initialize my sphere data like this:

```
Scene scene = Scene();
scene.addSphere(glm::vec3(-1.0, 1.0, -1.0), 1.0);
scene.addSphere(glm::vec3(0.0, 1.0, 0.0), 0.1);
scene.addSphere(glm::vec3(5.0, 0.5, 0.0), 0.5);
scene.addSphere(glm::vec3(5.0, 3.5, 0.0), 0.75);

std::vector<SphereUBO> sphereData;
for (int i = 0; i < scene.spheres.size(); i++) {
    SphereUBO sphere;
    sphere.position = scene.spheres[i].position;
    sphere.radius = scene.spheres[i].radius;
    sphere.albedo = glm::vec3(scene.spheres[i].material.albedo[0], scene.spheres[i].material.albedo[1], scene.spheres[i].material.albedo[2]);
    sphereData.push_back(sphere);
}
```

I have printed out sphereData to ensure the data is passed along properly. Finally, I update the contents of the buffer:

```
glBindBuffer(GL_UNIFORM_BUFFER, sphereUBO);
glBufferSubData(GL_UNIFORM_BUFFER, 0, sizeof(SphereUBO) * sphereData.size(), sphereData.data());
```

However, I only see one sphere rendered! I have confirmed that all of the spheres are rendering, but they are somehow all the same. I have this function in my fragment shader:

```
bool raycast(Ray ray, out HitPoint hitPoint) {
    bool hit = false;
    float minHitDistance = 10000;
    float hitDistance;

    for (int i = 0; i < u_numSpheres; i++) {
        if (sphereIntersection(u_spheres[i].position, u_spheres[i].radius, ray, hitDistance)) {
            hit = true;

            if (hitDistance < minHitDistance) {
                minHitDistance = hitDistance;
                hitPoint.position = ray.origin + ray.direction * minHitDistance;
                hitPoint.normal = normalize(hitPoint.position - u_spheres[i].position);
                hitPoint.material = Material(u_spheres[i].albedo);
            }
        }
    }

return hit;
```

}

I know they are all the same because when I don't do a for loop and I just check for the first or second sphere, they render the same.

I have my buffer/uniforms declared up here:

```
uniform int u_numSpheres;

layout(std140) uniform Sphere{
    vec3 position;
    float radius;
    vec3 albedo;
} u_spheres[32];
```

Answer (score 3):

> ```
> glGetUniformBlockIndex(shaderProgram, "Spheres")
> ```

First, the typo: "Spheres" is not a valid uniform block name, so this almost certainly returned `GL_INVALID_INDEX`, which would cause the call to `glUniformBlockBinding` to fail.

But more importantly, even if you named it "Sphere" to match your UBO definition... there *still* is no uniform block named "Sphere". However, there is a uniform block named `Sphere[0]`. And one named `Sphere[1]`. And so forth.

See, the problem is that you think `Sphere` is single uniform block. It is not. It is an array *of uniform blocks*, not a uniform block *containing* an array. That's what it means when you [declare an interface block as an array](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Interface_Block_(GLSL)#Syntax). You have 32 uniform blocks (which really should have caused a compile error all on its own).

What you really want is to declare a `struct` called `Sphere` and then have a uniform block containing an array of such types. Also, [stop using `vec3`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38172697/734069).